# Using Require with underscore Map causes require notloaded exception

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

I am trying to map a list of data to my array as following:

```
this.data = [];
_.map(dataList, function(element){
    var logic = require('./'+element+'/'+element);
    var tempalte = require('text!./' + element + '/' + element + '.html');
    return { Logic : logic, Template : tempalte };
});
```

I keep getting the following error when trying it:
"Module name "..." has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded"

what am i doing wrong here? is there no option to use underscore map with require?

Thanks

Comment: Should you not assign return value to something?

Comment: If you have read the linked docs you would know what the problem is.

Comment: andlrc - thats not a very helpful comment, I have read the linked doc but still wasnt able to make it work, if you have any idea why and how can i get it to work please do tell.

Answer (score 1):

`require.js` actually analyzes your code statically when loading it, and searches for modules to be loaded. Actually this happens because `require.js` implements the AMD (asynchrouns module definition) specification and not CommonJS. This syntax is possible just as a helper (or syntactic sugar) for us as developers. This way, when your parent module is loaded, actually all its dependencies are loaded too, and only then `require.js` "runs" it, which gives you the sense of synchronous loading (or at list the syntax of such).

**TL;DR:** You cannot load modules dynamically using this syntax.

In my opinion, loading modules dynamically like that is not a very good practice, as I'm not sure that you'll be able to optimize it using `r.js`.